# Delete numbers from a String

Tags: string, delphi, replace

I'd like to know how I can delete numbers from a String. I try to use StringReplace and I don't know how to tell the function that I want to replace numbers.

Here's what I tried:

```
StringReplace(mString, [0..9], '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

Comment: Well, Delphi XE and up support regular exression which can be used for string replace. It is in RegularExpressions and RegularExpressionsCore units

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple but effective.  Can be optimized, but should get you what you need as a start:

```
function RemoveNumbers(const aString: string): string;
var
  C: Char;
begin
  Result := '';
  for C in aString do begin
      if not CharInSet(C, ['0'..'9']) then
      begin
        Result := Result + C;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Agreed.  Although I am a BIG fan of regular expressions, Nick's solution to this particular problem is way faster.  Anything more complicated and I'd go with RegEx in a heartbeat!

Comment: You might consider using a [`TStringBuilder`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringBuilder) instead to avoid unnecessary memory reallocations while appending characters: `SB := TStringBuilder.Create(Length(aString));... SB.Append(C); ... Result := SB.ToString; SB.Free;` This is similar to the concept of Wouter's answer, just with a class wrapper.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty quick inplace version.

```
procedure RemoveDigits(var s: string);
var
  i, j: Integer;
  pc: PChar;
begin
  j := 0;
  pc := PChar(@s[1]);
  for i := 0 to Length(s) - 1 do
    if pc[i] in ['0'..'9'] then 
               //if CharInSet(pc[i], ['0'..'9']) for Unicode version
      Inc(j)
    else
      pc[i - j] := pc[i];
  SetLength(s, Length(s) - j);
end;
```

Comment: +1 for an inplace substitution, if the original string was large this type of method is much more memory efficient. any str := str + ? or other method that generates temporary string can very quickly buildup a large memory footprint which I've com across when simple conversion routines ( hex to bin, base64, etc ) are used on large data sets (a few meg )

Answer (score 5):

This has the same output as Nick's version, but this is more than 3 times as fast with short strings. The longer the text, the bigger the difference.

```
function RemoveNumbers2(const aString: string): string;
var
  C:Char; Index:Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  SetLength(Result, Length(aString));
  Index := 1;
  for C in aString do
    if not CharInSet(C, ['0' .. '9']) then
    begin
      Result[Index] := C;
      Inc(Index);
    end;
  SetLength(Result, Index-1);
end;
```

Don't waste precious CPU cycles if you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

Well I was tired of looking for already build functions so I've create my own:

```
   function RemoveNumbers(const AValue: string): string;
   var
      iCar : Integer;
      mBuffer : string;
   begin
      mBuffer := AValue;

      for iCar := Length(mBuffer) downto 1 do
      begin
         if (mBuffer[iCar] in ['0'..'9']) then
            Delete(mBuffer,iCar,1);
      end;
      Result := mBuffer;
   end;
```

Comment: Your function will fail, the for loop counter is cached and you're *shortening* your string in the loop.

Comment: But you could resolve this issue by reverting the order of deletes (using `for ... downto` instead). Only remember that characters in `string` are indexed from `1`, not from `0`.

Comment: I like Nick's version better. He wrote cleaner and more readable code and unlikely to break.  And yours uses more memory and is probably slower.  In a pathological case where I pass in 'a123908908203809....' (a 2 gigabyte string where only the first character is a non-digit) string, his would still work.  Sweet. Yours? not so well. In a reverse case, with medium size strings, and only one digit to remove, yours might well be faster and the memory use difference might not matter, but its still less readable.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
function RemoveNonAlpha(srcStr : string) : string;
const
CHARS = ['0'..'9'];
var i : integer;
begin
result:='';
for i:=0 to length(srcStr) do
if  (srcstr[i] in CHARS) then
result:=result+srcStr[i];
end   ;
```

you can call it like this

edit2.text:=RemoveNonAlpha(edit1.text);

Comment: This worked, but the function is inverted : it is removing the alpha chars :p

Answer (score -1):

StringReplace does not accept a set as the second argument. Maybe someone will have a more suitable approach, but this works:

```
StringReplace(mString, '0', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
StringReplace(mString, '1', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);    
StringReplace(mString, '2', '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

etc.

Comment: Yuck! Can you say `DRY` (Don't Repeat Yourself)? Sorry, but I have to downvote this as a *horrific* solution to the question asked.

Comment: Agree.. you could at least loop.. for i := 0 to 9 do StringReplace(mString, I, '', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);

Comment: Hey, Ken, go easy on me!  :-) "Horrific?" Yes, a for-loop has advantages.  But, sometimes, adding complexity adds errors.  John's code (unless he edits it after I've posted this) is a good example: first, it fails to compile. Assuming he intended "i" to be an integer, the proper code is bit tricky. The second parameter should be chr(ord('0') + i), no? Or the for-loop should be for ch := chr('0') to chr('9'). Both add a bit of complexity & don't really answer his question directly, which is how to use StringReplace. I figured the OP could easily revise the code as you suggest.

Comment: @RobertFrank both our code snips won't work because StringReplace is a function :)  That said, "horrific" is a strong word here...