# How to delete numbers in the string of Delphi letters

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-7

I have a string, I set the coordinates for the selection of letters, but sometimes they mix up and I asked the coordinates with the numbers, how do I make that if for example `'105DYUDXB28DYU13'` had it done `'DYUDXBDYU'`

```
tmpT.Put:=Trim(MidStr(S,8,6))+Trim(MidStr(S,37,3));
```

[image]

Comment: Iterate through the string's characters building a new string. Discard the characters that you don't want.

Comment: Or if you want to make it flexible (by using e.g. user entered patterns), use regex.

Comment: @Victoria: while regexes have their use, I don't think this is one of them. Regexes are not nearly as performant as a simple loop that omits digits while copying from one string to another. IOW: if you have a problem, and use regexes to solve it, then you have wo problems. <g>

Comment: @Rudy, Sure. But it's good for user entered patterns (at least for educated users :)

Comment: Sorry, marked this is a dupe of [Delete numbers from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10838468/576719), but realized that there were no good answer that covered the delphi-7 restriction.

Comment: @LURD there are answers in that link that work in Delphi 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution with good performance is as follows (`uses Character`):

```
function RemoveNumbers(const AString: string): string;
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
  SetLength(result, AString.Length);
  j := 0;
  for i := 1 to AString.Length do
    if not AString[i].IsDigit then
    begin
      inc(j);
      result[j] := AString[i];
    end;
  SetLength(result, j);
end;
```

This function uses a few language and library features introduced after Delphi 7. To make this work in Delphi 7, you need to rewrite it slightly:

```
function RemoveNumbers(const AString: string): string;
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
  SetLength(result, Length(AString));
  j := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(AString) do
    if not (AString[i] in ['0'..'9']) then
    begin
      inc(j);
      result[j] := AString[i];
    end;
  SetLength(result, j);
end;
```

*The fine print:* `TCharHelper.IsDigit` is Unicode-aware, and so it will return `true` for all Unicode digits. For instance, it will return `true` for

- ٣ (U+0663: ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT THREE),
- ੪ (U+0A6A: GURMUKHI DIGIT FOUR),
- ௫ (U+0BEB: TAMIL DIGIT FIVE),
- ៥ (U+17E5: KHMER DIGIT FIVE), and
- ᠗ (U+1817: MONGOLIAN DIGIT SEVEN).

If you only want to treat the characters `'0'..'9'` as digits, you can use the modernized version of the Delphi 7 test:

```
if not CharInSet(AString[i], ['0'..'9']) then
```

Comment: Not sure that can be described as perfect. Might be better to loop twice and do a single allocation. Since the question is not about performance I'd neglect that aspect. And the answer surely should be for Delphi 7. Further, doesn't the Unicode standard define more than 10 digits?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Indeed, `IsDigit` will consider more characters than only 0..9 as digits. But the desired semantics depends on the actual situation, which I cannot know any details about. (And I do think it is good practice at SO to give a 'modern' solution as well as a solution suitable for the specified Delphi version, for the benefit of other people that might see the Q.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Regarding the performance, surely *truncating* a string doesn't cause a copy of it?

Comment: yes you are right but on the basis of Andreas all earned, all thank you

Comment: Truncating is another heap allocation operation. They can be extraordinarily expensive, especially in comparison with accessing memory that has just been brought into cache. I don't know which is faster, and that depends on usage and probably other factors. But "perfect" is hard to justify.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thank you for your clarification. I have changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Better also to initialise j to zero, increment before assignment, and then set length to j

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Totally agree, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Also code with procedure and var parameter:

```
procedure RemoveNumbers(var Text: String);
var
    Index: Integer;
begin
    for Index := Length(Text) downto 1 do
         if Text[Index] in ['0'..'9']
         then Text := Copy(Text, 1, Index - 1) + Copy(Text, Index + 1, Length(Text) - Index);
end;

var
    Text: String;

begin
    Text := '105DYUDXB28DYU13';
    RemoveNumbers(Text);
    WriteLn(Text);
end.
```

Comment: Performance-wise, this is far from optimal. It will cause a large number of allocations and copies to be made in memory.